# How to navigate to a page section using vueJS/Quasar (q-tree)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, vue.js, quasar-framework

I am using Quasar for vue.js development.

I want to use the q-tree but instead of loading a q-tab-panel when tree objects are selected, I want it to navigate to a specific section of the same q-tab-panel using the `href="#some-id"`.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this??

Here is the Quasar/VueJS code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <q-splitter
      v-model="splitterModel"
      style="height: 400px"
    >

      <template v-slot:before>
        <div class="q-pa-md">
          <q-tree
            :nodes="simple"
            node-key="label"
            selected-color="primary"
            :selected.sync="selected"
            default-expand-all
          />
        </div>
      </template>

      <template v-slot:after>
        <q-tab-panels
          v-model="selected"
          animated
          transition-prev="jump-up"
          transition-next="jump-up"
        >
          <q-tab-panel name="Relax Hotel">
            <div class="text-h4 q-mb-md">Welcome</div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis praesentium cumque magnam odio iure quidem, quod illum numquam possimus obcaecati commodi minima assumenda consectetur culpa fuga nulla ullam. In, libero.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis praesentium cumque magnam odio iure quidem, quod illum numquam possimus obcaecati commodi minima assumenda consectetur culpa fuga nulla ullam. In, libero.</p>
          </q-tab-panel>

          <q-tab-panel name="Food">
            <div class="text-h4 q-mb-md">Food</div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis praesentium cumque magnam odio iure quidem, quod illum numquam possimus obcaecati commodi minima assumenda consectetur culpa fuga nulla ullam. In, libero.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis praesentium cumque magnam odio iure quidem, quod illum numquam possimus obcaecati commodi minima assumenda consectetur culpa fuga nulla ullam. In, libero.</p>
          </q-tab-panel>

          <q-tab-panel name="Room service">
            <div class="text-h4 q-mb-md">Room service</div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis praesentium cumque magnam odio iure quidem, quod illum numquam possimus obcaecati commodi minima assumenda consectetur culpa fuga nulla ullam. In, libero.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis praesentium cumque magnam odio iure quidem, quod illum numquam possimus obcaecati commodi minima assumenda consectetur culpa fuga nulla ullam. In, libero.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis praesentium cumque magnam odio iure quidem, quod illum numquam possimus obcaecati commodi minima assumenda consectetur culpa fuga nulla ullam. In, libero.</p>
          </q-tab-panel>

          <q-tab-panel name="Room view">
            <div class="text-h4 q-mb-md">Room view</div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis praesentium cumque magnam odio iure quidem, quod illum numquam possimus obcaecati commodi minima assumenda consectetur culpa fuga nulla ullam. In, libero.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis praesentium cumque magnam odio iure quidem, quod illum numquam possimus obcaecati commodi minima assumenda consectetur culpa fuga nulla ullam. In, libero.</p>
          </q-tab-panel>
        </q-tab-panels>
      </template>
    </q-splitter>
  </div>
</template>
```

And here is CodePen link:
https://codepen.io/pen/define/

Thanks!